# Mojo IOLoop blocks app when ran

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I use [`Mojo::IOLoop`](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::IOLoop) to perform background tasks that should be run every so often, and am doing this using `Mojo::IOLoop::recurring`. I do this within the Mojo app itself:

```
sub startup {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->setup_routes();
    ... more setup
    my $sleep_time = $self->config()->{sleep_time};
    Mojo::IOLoop->recurring($sleep_time => sub {
        my $sync = My::BackgroundTask->new(
            sleep_time => $sleep_time,
        );
        $sync->run();
    });

    local $SIG{TERM} = sub {
        Mojo::IOLoop->stop_gracefully;
    };
}
```

When the time comes for the above loop to run, when trying to view the actual app the site times out, and when it's finished the app is available again. Not sure why this is happening, would someone be able to explain?

EDIT:
`My::BackgroundTask::run`

```
sub run {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;

    while ( scalar(@{$data}) > 0 ) {
        my @batch = splice(@{$data}, 0, 100);
        $self->schema->update_batch_of_data( \@batch );

        # sleep for a while to not be rude :P
        sleep ($self->sleep_time);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find the problem is in `My::BackgroundTask` which you haven't shown. Have you checked whether the parent task is actually blocked or simply unable to get resources?

Comment: It's not especially relevant, but setting `local $SIG{TERM} = sub { ... }` is wrong as the value will revert to its original state as soon as `startup` exits. Just `$SIG{TERM} = sub { ... }` is correct

Comment: @Borodin, hmm I didn't think about the problem being in the task, as all it does is query the database in increments, calling sleep inbetween. Would calling sleep() be the reason why it is blocking the app?

Comment: I don't know how `Mojo::IOLoop` works internally, but it's possible. Are you saying that it sleeps for `$sleep_time` seconds? Because that's not how it's supposed to work. It should *exit* and continue the process next time the `recurring` starts it up. As it is, you're trying to start another copy of the task of the task each time `recurring` kicks in, and maybe your task is hanging because it's unable to start more than one task? Just a guess, Does it ever return from `$sync->run()`? And what sort of thing is `$sync`?

Comment: @Borodin Well that's interesting! `$sync->run()` is just performing a database query multiple times, which I'll add to the question. I'm sure it returns successfully as I can see it runs multiple times (recurring)

Comment: @Borodin yeah seems to have been because of the sleep inbetween, thanks! Any suggestions on how to be friendly when calling external sources and not milking them in one go? :P

Comment: Yes, you need a similar `recurring` timer, but only do a fraction of the work at each step

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that it sleeps for `$sleep_time` seconds? Because that's not how it's supposed to work. It should *exit* and continue the process next time the `recurring` starts it up. As it is, you're trying to start another copy of the task of the task each time `recurring` kicks in, and maybe your task is hanging because it's unable to start more than one task? Just a guess, Does it ever return from `$sync->run()`? And what sort of thing is `$sync`?
                    – Borodin

yeah seems to have been because of the sleep inbetween, thanks! Any suggestions on how to be friendly when calling external sources and not milking them in one go? :P – a7omiton

Yes, you need a similar `recurring` timer, but only do a fraction of the work at each step
                    – Borodin